# WMI registered as InstrumentationClass(InstrumentationType.Event) when Fire I can´t see it

Tags: windows, wmi

This is a question on the old Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) that I can´t figger out. If I tag a class as [InstrumentationClass(InstrumentationType.Instance)] it works fine. But if I do it with [InstrumentationClass(InstrumentationType.Event)] it doesn´t.
I created an instalation class like this:

```
[assembly: Instrumented(@"Root\RabbitMQMonitor")]
namespace RabbitMQMonitor.Services
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class Installer4WMI : DefaultManagementProjectInstaller { }
}
```

Then I tagged this class like this:

```
[InstrumentationClass(InstrumentationType.Instance)]
public class JustToSeeInstances
{
    public string Message;        
}
```

Then I register it using eather InstallUtill.exe or in the code calling:

```
Instrumentation.RegisterAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

When I call the Publish:

```
Instrumentation.Publish(new JustToSeeInstances()
{ Message = "Instrumentation.Fire(new InstrumentationWarning() executed" });
```

And it works. In powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\ARipollJ> get-wmiobject -namespace "Root/RabbitMQMonitor" -class JustToSeeInstances

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : JustToSeeInstances
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : JustToSeeInstances
__RELPATH        : JustToSeeInstances.InstanceId="3839",ProcessId="da1d1658-84aa-4394-b0d8-b80ceddfecc7"
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : W7TC2I198DTECN
__NAMESPACE      : Root\RabbitMQMonitor
__PATH           : \\W7TC2I198DTECN\Root\RabbitMQMonitor:JustToSeeInstances.InstanceId="3839",ProcessId="da1d1658-84aa-
                   4394-b0d8-b80ceddfecc7"
InstanceId       : 3839
Message          : Instrumentation.Fire(new InstrumentationWarning() executed
ProcessId        : da1d1658-84aa-4394-b0d8-b80ceddfecc7
```

BUT, if I do this with an event:

```
[InstrumentationClass(InstrumentationType.Event)]
public class InstrumentationWarning
{
    public string VirtualHost;
    public string Queue;
    public string Message;
}
```

And then call Fire:

```
Instrumentation.Fire(new InstrumentationWarning()
{ VirtualHost = virtualHost, Queue = queue, Message = message });
```

It never shows eather in WMI checking tool either in powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\ARipollJ> get-wmiobject -namespace "Root/RabbitMQMonitor" -class InstrumentationWarning
PS C:\Users\ARipollJ>
```

Aclaration: Publish is for instances and Fire for events. I already switched just to try and it didn´t work eather. I am really stacked with this. I would really appreciate some light on it.

Comment: It seems that you try to receive events with `get-wmiobject` instead of [registering to them](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849840.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Clijsters. It was that:

If I register to my event. PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\ARipollJ> register-wmiEvent -class 'InstrumentarionWarning'
```

Then I Instrumentation.Fire it an then I use "Get-Event":

```
PS C:\Users\ARipollJ> Get-Event


ComputerName     :
RunspaceId       : fc02e8ce-849e-473e-b5b9-d5eac39eb130
EventIdentifier  : 1
Sender           : System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher
SourceEventArgs  : System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs
SourceArgs       : {System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher, System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs}
SourceIdentifier : 1e87f848-276b-447d-bbb0-c985dc27b347
TimeGenerated    : 20/04/2016 11:39:37
MessageData      :

ComputerName     :
RunspaceId       : fc02e8ce-849e-473e-b5b9-d5eac39eb130
EventIdentifier  : 2
Sender           : System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher
SourceEventArgs  : System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs
SourceArgs       : {System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher, System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs}
SourceIdentifier : 1e87f848-276b-447d-bbb0-c985dc27b347
TimeGenerated    : 20/04/2016 11:40:03
MessageData      :
```

Here they are!